# Magento: Unable to login both customer and admin, and unable to add to cart

Tags: php, caching, authentication, magento-1.9, cart

I have tried setting the cookie lifetime to 86400 and configuring other settings from the magento backend but still doesn't work. I tried clearing the cache and somehow solves the problem for a few minutes then it won't work again. Please help.

Comment: have you set cookies path and cookies domain?

Comment: Yep. 

Cookies path: "/"
Cookies Domain: ".site.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do config as below

go to admin->system->configuration-> Web -> Session Cookie Management

```
Cookie Lifetime : 86400
Cookie Domain : .yoursite.com
Use HTTP only : yes
Cookie Path : /
```

Or Comment below code

Go to: Magento Folder/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

and comment out the following that starts at about line 78 as you see below.

```
/*
  session_set_cookie_params(
   $this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
   $this->getCookie()->getPath()
   $this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
   $this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
   $this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
  );
*/
```

Comment: It is currently configured like that. Still no luck.

Comment: did you check in system.log or exception.log files

Comment: I did. I don't see any errors correlating to the problem. :/

Comment: also change Cookie Lifetime = 3600

Comment: The recent solution seemed to work. But I believe modifying the core file is not the best fix. I'll try to research more on what could have been a possible cause. Anyway thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Thanks mate,  you can also overwrite the core file in local folder and make changes as per our requirement.it'll be not effected